# Mysql subtracting values using row selected from min timestamp, grouping by id

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subtraction

I've been at this for a few hours now to no avail, pulling my hair out.

Edit: Im wanting to calculate the difference between the overall_exp column by using the same data from 1 day ago to calculate the greatest 'gain' for each user

Currently I'm take a row, then select a row from 1 day ago based on the first rows timestamp then subtract the overall_exp column from the 2 rows and order by that result whilst grouping by user_id

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/501c8

Here is what i currently have, however the logic is completely wrong so im pulling 0 results

```
SELECT rsn, ts.timestamp, @original_ts := SUBDATE( ts.timestamp, INTERVAL 1 DAY), ts.overall_exp, ts.overall_exp - previous.overall_exp AS gained_exp
    FROM tracker AS ts
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, MIN( TIMESTAMP ) , overall_exp
    FROM tracker
    WHERE TIMESTAMP >= @original_ts
    GROUP BY user_id
) previous 
    ON ts.user_id = previous.user_id
JOIN users
    ON ts.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY ts.user_id
ORDER BY gained_exp DESC
```

Comment: All the sample data in the SQLFiddle is for the same day (11 May 2013), so no matter what query you run against it, you will never get a row for the day before any given row's timestamp. Also, it's far from clear **what** you are trying to achieve - your existing question only describes **how** you are trying to achieve it.

Comment: Updated OP and SQLFiddle

Comment: Thanks, that's clearer, but it's still a little unclear - do you want one row per user per day, and if so which timestamp from one day do you want to compare with which timestamp from the previous day? Alternatively, do you want one row in your result set for each row in `tracker`, comparing the date and time in each row with the earliest date and time in the preceding 24 hours (which appears to be the logic behind the posted query)? Or something else?

Comment: I want 1 result per user, checking through every row of the tracker table for that user and comparing it to the earliest timestamp 1 day ago, giving each users biggest 'gain/difference' from all of their data in the tracker table. I suck at wording things it would seem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a self-join:

```
select t.user_id, max(t.overall_exp - tprev.overall_exp)
from tracker t join
     tracker tprev
     on tprev.user_id = t.user_id and
        date(tprev.timestamp) = date(SUBDATE(t.timestamp, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
group by t.user_id
```

A key here is converting the timestamps to dates, so the comparison is exact.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select u.*, max(t.`timestamp`)-min(t.`timestamp`) gain
from users u
left join tracker t 
on u.id = t.user_id and
   t.`timestamp` >= date_sub(date(now()), interval 1 day) and
   t.`timestamp` < date_add(date(now()), interval 1 day)
group by u.id
order by gain desc
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c8dc/3).